# How to find a key in json and print it python

Tags: python, json

I have the next data:

```
{
"AlignedDataCtrlr": {
        "Enabled": false,
        "Measurands": {
          "readOnly": false,
          "value": []
        },
        "Interval": {
          "readOnly": false,
          "value": 50,
          "unit": "seconds"
        },
        "TxEndedMeasurands": {
          "readOnly": false,
          "value": []
        },
        "TxEndedInterval": {
          "readOnly": true,
          "value": 50,
          "unit": "seconds"
        }
      },
      "AuthCacheCtrlr": {
        "Enabled": false,
        "AuthCacheEnabled": {
          "readOnly": false,
          "value": true
        },
        "AuthCacheLifeTime": {
          "readOnly": true,
          "value": true
        }
      },
    ...
    }
```

And I want to print every variable that is not read only, for example print Measurands and its values, Interval, etc...

I start with

```
import json
file = open("./configs/configuration.json")
config = json.load(file)

    for each_ctrlr in config:
        for each_key in each_ctrlr:
            if 'readOnly' in each_key:
                print(each_key)
```

But there's nothing printing...

Comment: In the first loop you iterate over keys and in the second/nested one - ober chars of the key. You want to iterate over values in the first loop and try to get `readOnly` key...

Comment: And how can I iterate over values and not keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to iterate through key-values at the same time, use `.items()`
If you just want to iterate over the key, use `.keys()`
If you just want to iterate over the values, use `.values()`

```
import json


with open("./configs/configuration.json", "r") as f:
    config = json.load(f)
    for k, v in config.items():
        for k2, v2 in v.items():
            if isinstance(v2, dict) and v2.get("readOnly"):
                print(k2, v2)
```

Output

```
TxEndedInterval {'readOnly': True, 'value': 50, 'unit': 'seconds'}
AuthCacheLifeTime {'readOnly': True, 'value': True}
```